# Как сделать чтобы по клику на инлайновую кнопку в чатботе загружался следующий контент?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить следующую задачу:

Клиент в чатботе выбирает нужный товар, но у него должны загружаться не все сразу, а только три. Потом, по клику на инлайновую кнопку "Показать ещё", появляется остальная часть контента. Вот фрагмент:

```
    elif (message.text == '2009 - 2012'):
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        orderbtn = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Перейти на сайт', url='...')
        morebtn = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Узнать у менеджера об этом авто', url='...')
        markup.add(orderbtn, morebtn)
        photo1 = open('venv/images/1.10.jpg', 'rb')
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Марка: Toyota\n \U0001F539 Пробег: 132000 км\n \U0001F539 Год: 2010\n \U0001F539 Цена: 15000 $')
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Кликай, чтобы увидеть более детальное описание\U0001F447', reply_markup=markup)
        bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text='Марка: Toyota\n Пробег: 132000 км\n Год: 2010\n Цена: 15000 $')

        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        orderbtn = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Перейти на сайт', url='https://the-best-auto.com/product/3827')
        morebtn = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Узнать у менеджера об этом авто', url='https://t.me/manager_the_best_avto')
        markup.add(orderbtn, morebtn)
        photo2 = open('venv/images/1.11(1).jpg', 'rb')
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo2)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Марка: Mazda\n \U0001F539 Пробег: 224236 км\n \U0001F539 Год: 2011\n \U0001F539 Цена: 10800 $')
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Кликай, чтобы увидеть более детальное описание\U0001F447', reply_markup=markup)
        bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text='Марка: Mazda\n Пробiг: 224236 км\n Год: 2011\n Цена: 10800 $')

        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        orderbtn = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Перейти на сайт', url='https://the-best-auto.com/product/4097')
        morebtn = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Узнать у менеджера ою этом авто', url='https://t.me/manager_the_best_avto')
        more = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Показать еще', callback_data='1')
        markup.add(orderbtn, morebtn, more)
        photo3 = open('venv/images/1.12(2).jpg', 'rb')
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo3)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Марка: Volkswagen\n \U0001F539 Пробег: 220793 км\n \U0001F539 Год: 2012\n \U0001F539 Цена: 13700 $')
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Кликай, чтобы увидеть более детальное описание\U0001F447', reply_markup=markup)
        bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text='Марка: Volkswagen\n Пробег: 220793 км\n Год: 2012\n Цена: 13700 $')

    elif (message.text == 'Показать еще'):
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        orderbtn = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Перейти на сайт', url='...')
        morebtn = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Узнать у менеджера об этом авто'', url='...')
        markup.add(orderbtn, morebtn)
        photo4 = open('venv/images/1.11(2).jpg', 'rb')
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo4)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Марка: Volvo\n \U0001F539 Пробег: 217800  км\n \U0001F539 Год: 2011\n \U0001F539 Цена: 14800 $')
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Кликай, чтобы увидеть более детальное описание\U0001F447', reply_markup=markup)
        bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text='Марка: Volvo\n Пробег: 217800  км\n Год: 2011\n Цена: 14800 $')
```